# Having a lot of data in an application

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am planning on creating an android application sometime in the future in which I'll want it to display a lot of constant data on the screen.

I'm not sure the best way to do this but I see two options:

1. Storing the data within the code itself such as creating a constants class.
2. Using an embedded database to hold the data.

I'm guessing option #2 is the best way? But it just seems weird using a database if I'm not going to be doing any updating to the database, I would only be selecting.

The total amount of data that I need the application to display is maybe about 400 lines consisting of a string and two integers...

Is there a different way people use for such a situation that I don't know about?

Comment: Your answer depends a lot on what kind of data and how, exactly, you plan on using it.  There's nothing wrong with using SQLite for read only, particularly when you have "a lot" of data.  The overwhelming majority of database transactions in any given day are selects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it just seems weird using a database if I'm not going to be doing
>   any updating to the database

I am totally disagree with you. Database is not only for updating. It can be used as a better storage and definitely a best way for searching. So as you want to preserve the data then it is definitely wise to use database.

But if you want to handle data which will not persists , i,e you will use different datas for different run then you can use temporary class or other data structure to store data.

Finally, If you are planning to have portability then File storage is an easier solution.

SO you can see, that it totally depends on what you want.